# Spring MVC URL not getting resolved correctly

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I created a Spring project in Eclipse.  The problem is that, the URL is not getting resolved in the way I think it should.

web.xml

```
<servlet>
          <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
          <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
          <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/files/*</url-pattern>
     <url-pattern>/filestest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This is my mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd      
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

     <mvc:annotation-driven />
     <context:component-scan base-package="com.github.myproject.controllers" />

</beans>
```

This is my Controller file:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/filestest")
public class TestController {
    @RequestMapping(value="", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String getBase() {
        System.out.println("Base");
        return "Base";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String getRoot() {
        System.out.println("Root");
        return "Root";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="abc", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String getABC() {
        System.out.println("ABC");
        return "ABC";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/abc", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String getBaseAbc() {
        System.out.println("Base ABC");
        return "Base ABC";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/{pathVar}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String getPathVar(@PathVariable(value="pathVar") String pathVar) {
        System.out.println(pathVar);
        return pathVar;
    }
}
```

Here are the output I got

http://mylocalhost.com/filestest/abc - 404

http://mylocalhost.com/filestest/    - 404

http://mylocalhost.com/filestest     - Valid Output - "Base"

From my understanding of [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/mvc.html), the web.xml should route all /filestest requests to DispatcherServlet -> which routes the request to my Controller -> which should then match the correct method.

Can someone please help me figure out why  I am getting 404 File not found error for URLs - http://mylocalhost.com/filestest/abc and http://mylocalhost.com/filestest/ when I try to deploy and test my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `/filestest` from the controller's `RequestMapping` annotation.

Spring is using only the mapped path part (`*`) so there is no need to have the servlet prefix inside your `RequestMapping`.

Comment: Yes.  That was the reason.  So, looks like, given an URL, Spring splits it down to parts that match "url-mappping" in web.xml, parts that match Controller's RequestMapping and method's RequestMapping.